# How can I draw back the second part of a proposed tag info edit if the first one was rejected?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

About a month ago, I posted a description of the [ifc-open-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ifc-open-shell/info) tag. The first part (usage guidance) was rejected. Whereas the second part (description) is still pending consideration. But without the first one, this wait seems to be forever. How can I revoke a description? If it's not possible, will it be automatically deleted after a while if no one reviews it?

Comment: Went ahead and rejected it; don't plagiarize tag wikis in the future.